# Downsized main partition and now boots to grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I used the following commands and rebooted to get where I'm at:

```
fdisk /dev/sda1,
d,
n,
a,
w
```

I'd like to be able to boot Ubuntu again

Comment: Boot some live cd, `grub-install` on the disk's `/dev/sda`, could do.

Comment: On a side-note: Did you shrink the file-system in sda1? If you care about your data, you should do that before continuing.